# directory for public and private file in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to create a website for selling quality photos using Laravel framework.
I want to show everyone the photo mockup on the home screen.
But the original file(zip) can be downloaded after purchase.
Is it best to place the mockup file in the `Storage/app/public` path and the zip file in the `Storage/app/files` path?
If I do, I can access the mockup file using `php artisan storage:link`and display it on the home screen. But I have no idea how to download the zip file.

If this method of storing files and mockups is correct, secure and standard, please tell me how to access the zip file.
But if this is the wrong way, tell me the right place to put the files and mockups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's public to everyone then there is no problem to make it public, so If you were to use your local driver and would want to make files accessible in your storage folder then you would run an artisan command like below

`php artisan storage:link`

This will ensure that files are accessible publicly as example.com/public/storage/whateverfile.

However, for the people who have purchased the image, you need to use authentication or authorization to handle it, eg. if you want the files to be only accessible to authenticated user then maybe you can put the files in storage/myViewFile which will make sure that files in the folder aren't publicly accessible. Then using a controller with an auth middleware or route with middleware you can make files accessible.

```php
Route::get('/storage/files/{file}', 'FilesController@show')->middleware('auth');
```

and for downloading files you can do it in the `show` method using laravel download response

```php
return response()->download($pathToFile);
//or
return response()->download($pathToFile, $name, $headers);
//or
return response()->download($pathToFile)->deleteFileAfterSend();
```

Comment: So the only way to access files that are in the `storage/file/one.zip` path is through the route and controller, and the user No crossing the route and controller cannot download the file via link and other methods. is it correct?

Comment: @MajidRostamian, yes, and it because laravel use `middleware` to handle authentication or authorization, which means if the user is not logged in or does not have the permission, the code within the `show` method will not even run.